# Apache Proxy Error

Tags: apache, proxy

I am getting the following error intermittently on my server:

```
**Proxy Error** 
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

The error logs show the following:

```
[Sun Feb 06 03:06:00 2011] [error] [client 82.43.154.57] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /login, referer: https://demo.XXXXX.us/
[Sun Feb 06 03:06:30 2011] [error] [client 82.43.154.57] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server XXXXX.us
[Sun Feb 06 03:06:30 2011] [error] [client 82.43.154.57] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /
[Sun Feb 06 03:13:31 2011] [error] [client 82.43.154.57] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server XXXXX.us
[Sun Feb 06 03:13:31 2011] [error] [client 82.43.154.57] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /
```

I have read a lot of posts suggesting connection timeout settings in tomcat and environment settings in Apache. I have set the following in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
   SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
   SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also set the following in tomcat server.xml:

```
<Connector port="9080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="9443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Also, once the error occurs, I have to start a new browser for the error to disappear as it continues to show even on a refresh. Secondly, I am using htaccess to rewrite the url. Don't know if this has any impact on the error?

EDIT>
My server is running on 150mb of free memory at normal times and can drop quite low but not at the exact times of the above error. Would this cause such an error?

I would appreciate any ideas people have.

Thank you.

Comment: First, set Apache's loglevel to debug and try to catch more information about the issue. Second, you might really have memory related issue. Use [VisualVM](http://java.net/projects/visualvm) and see how long your GC cycles take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Pear Mailer.

We were using Pear Mailer which uses a queue to stack emails ready for sending with a cron job. There was an error in the Pear script which was being called on every action on our site (making posts, sending messages etc..). Pear was crashing which in turn crashed the browser resulting in the above errors.

Disabling Pear resolved the problem, and tweaking the code got it working again.

It took so long to find the issue as we never thought Pear Mailer could cause such a response.

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar problem on our server after a mysql crash, and the only solution was to restart the server.

Comment: That is not really resolving the issue.  It does solve it short term, but I believe the question is looking for a more permanent solution.  Did you try anything to diagnose your similar issue before just resulting to restarting the server?

Comment: I have the same issue now, getting these Proxy errors in apache log, and apache at some times stops working, not sure why? then to make it work i have to restart it. Any help would appreciate?